# "in this way" vs "in the next way"

Tags: sentence-choice

1. The students are grouped in this way: 30 in each classroom.
2. The students are grouped in the next way: 30 in each classroom.

Which is the correct version and if both are correct which is the best to be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Next way* is unidiomatic here. *Next way* would be employed only if you had previously defined a sequence of 'ways' and mentioned at least one of them; the *next* way would then be the *way* which followed the most recently mentioned *way*.

> Students are grouped in three ways. In the first way, they are grouped 24 in each classroom. Our students are grouped in the next way: 30 in each classroom. The third way, 20 or fewer in each classroom, is rarely encountered.

The correct term for designating what immediately follows without respect to some previously defined sequence is *following*—or as you suggest simply *this*:

> The students are grouped in the following way: . . .
>   The students are grouped [in] this way: . . .

I assume you offer this sentence only as an example, not as something you would actually write. If not, you should be aware that in academic English brevity and conciseness are very highly valued, and this sentence would be regarded as deplorably verbose. You would do better to write:

> The students are grouped 30 in each classroom.